# No module named 'custom_transforms'

Tags: python, module, deep-learning, pytorch, importerror

I am working on a project (spatio-temporal video segmentation) in which I am using the [COSNET Model written in pytorch](https://github.com/carrierlxk/COSNet/blob/master/test_coattention_conf.py). While trying to run the model on google colab (specifically the part below) I get the error:

> No module named custom_transforms

I tried the `!pip install custom_transforms` but I get:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
>   custom_transforms (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for custom_transforms

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import custom_transforms as tr
    import torch
    from torchvision import transforms
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

    transforms = transforms.Compose([tr.RandomHorizontalFlip(), tr.Resize(scales=[0.5, 0.8, 1]), tr.ToTensor()])
```

Answer (score 0):

First, try this:

```py
!pip install torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as tr
```

If this does not work, it seems that this is the file that you need:

https://github.com/jfzhang95/DeepGrabCut-PyTorch/blob/master/dataloaders/custom_transforms.py

so you download it and import it.